# Save data to file and read data

Tags: vb.net, button

I actually got this :

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim a As StreamReader
    Dim b As String
    Dim c As String = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\WindowsApplication2\test.txt"

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Not File.Exists(c) Then
            Dim d As FileStream
            d = File.Create(c)
            d.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim button As New Button
        button.Location = New Drawing.Point(50, 50)
        button.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(170, 50)
        button.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Me.Controls.Add(button)
        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Enter a name.")
        Else
            File.AppendAllText(c, TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf)
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            MsgBox("Button created !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Saved")

        End If
    End Sub
```

I want than when I create a button when clicking on the button1, the new button be memorized in the .txt file, and when I restart the program, this reload the new button.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's a small MSDN article to get you started: [How to: Read text from a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx). You might also wanna read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: If all you need to save is the Text, just use a StringCollection in Settings.  Note that all the button you create are in the same spot so only the last one will show.  They also wont do anything when you click them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applicationsetting to save changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448694/applicationsetting-to-save-changes)